# LINQ complex delete and search query

Tags: c#, xml, linq, textbox

//assume that I have the following XML file.

```
<warehouse>
          <cat id="computer">
            <item>
              <SN>1</SN>
              <name>Toshiba</name>
              <quantity>12</quantity>
              <description>CPU: CORE I5 RAM: 3 GB HD: 512 GB</description>
              <price>400 USD</price>
            </item>
<item>
              <SN>22</SN>
              <name>Toshiba</name>
              <quantity>12</quantity>
              <description>CPU: CORE I5 RAM: 3 GB HD: 512 GB</description>
              <price>400 USD</price>
            </item>
          </cat>
          <cat id="Stationery">
            <item>
              <SN> 33 </SN>
              <name>note books</name>
              <quantity>250</quantity>
              <description>Caterpiller</description>
              <price>5 USD</price>
            </item>
        </cat>
        <cat id="Furniture">
            <item>
              <SN> 1 </SN>
              <name>dasd</name>
              <quantity>asdasd</quantity>
              <description>das</description>
              <price>dasd</price>
            </item>
<item>
              <SN>44</SN>
              <name>Toshiba</name>
              <quantity>12</quantity>
              <description>CPU: CORE I5 RAM: 3 GB HD: 512 GB</description>
              <price>400 USD</price>
            </item>

            <item> 
        </cat>
        </warehouse>
```

question 1 : I want to Delete `<item>` element and its child's using linq , where `<cat id="computer">` and `<SN>` has a specific value like 44 .

question 2 : I want to make a query using TextBox and Literal1 which return a specic `<item>` and its child's . this query should be in linq.

for example

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("/XML/Cat1.xml"));
        var persons = from person in xmlDoc.Descendants("item")
                      where person.Element("SN").Value.Equals(DropDownList1.Text)
                      select person;


        persons.Remove();


        foreach (XElement person in persons.ToList())
        {
            person.Remove();

        }
```

Comment: i want something like this code

XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("/XML/Cat1.xml"));
        var persons = from person in xmlDoc.Descendants("item")
                      where person.Element("SN").Value.Equals(DropDownList1.Text)
                      select person;


        persons.Remove();


        foreach (XElement person in persons.ToList())
        {
            person.Remove();

        }

Comment: Better add your efforts by editing your question.

Comment: Your query looks okay. What problem you are facing?

Comment: look at the main question please

Comment: i want to edit this query by additing the condition 

<cat id = 'computer'>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

```
xmlDoc.Root.Descendants("cat").Where(x => x.Attribute("id").Value == "computer")
      .Descendants("item").Where(x => x.Element("SN").Value.Trim() == Dropdownlist.Text)
      .Remove();
xmlDoc.Save(@"YourXML.xml");
```

And for filtering you can replace the values at specific places you like. Also, I have used `Trim` directly, better check for empty strings first in your actual code.

Question 2:-

```
var result = xmlDoc.Descendants("item")
             .Where(x => x.Element("SN").Value.Trim() == Dropdownlist.Text);
```

Comment: can u please edit this to make it where SN == Dropdownlist.text ??

Comment: @RefaatKh - Plz check nw.

Comment: thank you so much it works.

and what about the question 2 ?? do u have any solution for it ?

Comment: @RefaatKh - You're welcome. Don't filter by `cat`, omit that part for second question and directly use `item`. I will update that too.

Comment: how can i assign the result to Literal1 ??

Comment: This'll return a complete item node you need to fetch the particular item you wanna select from that.

Comment: i'm using this coe , but it dosent work 
 XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("/XML/XML.xml"));
        var result = xmlDoc.Descendants("item")
             .Where(x => x.Element("SN").Value.Trim() == TextBox1.Text);
        Literal1.Text = result.ToString();

i want to search for a specifc item throw SN==textbox.text and then return the value of result inside Literal1 after pressing a button

Comment: to be more accurate i want it to return the ( name , description , price) in this <item> for the givin SN in the textbox

Comment: XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("/XML/XML.xml"));
        var persons = from person in xmlDoc.Descendants("item")

                      select new
                      {
                          SN = person.Element("SN").Value,
                          name = person.Element("name").Value,
                          quantity = person.Element("quantity").Value,
                          description = person.Element("description").Value,
                          price = person.Element("price").Value,
                      foreach (var person in persons)

Comment: but i still want to add the cat id=dropdownlist.text condition

Comment: @RefaatKh - Okay what you did is correct, and for `cat` condition just do it the way I did for removing item.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding question one i would do something like this using method syntax:

```
  doc.Descendants("cat")
        .Where(x => String.Equals((string)x.Attribute("id"), "computer", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        .Elements("item")
        .Where(x => (string)x.Element("SN") == "44")
        .Remove();
```

Basically select all your cat elements and filter by attribute id = computer. Then select all items in each of those and filter through SN = 44.

Comment: can u please edit this to make it where SN == Dropdownlist.text ??